# Put Integer Pointer into Array

Tags: c

I tried to put the Ptr at the end of the frame in C.

```
void myFunction(uint8_t * Ptr)
{
 uint8_t frame[] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, *Ptr}
}

int _main()
{
 myFunction("Hello");
}
```

in this solution I put only the H of "Hello" into frame[4] because of the 8 bit.

After that I tried

```
    strcat((char*)frame, (char*) StateTxtPtr);
```

but it didn't work.

The solution should look like this:
frame = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, "H", "E", "L", "L", "O"}

Thanks for your help!

SOLUTION **

```
void myFunction(uint8_t * Ptr, uint32_t TxtSize)
{
 uint8_t frame[25] = {0x1, 0x2, 0x3, *Ptr}
 memcpy(&frame[3], Ptr, TxtSize); 
}

int _main()
{
 uint32_t TxtSize = strlen((char *)&txt[i][0]);
 myFunction("Hello", TxtSize);
}
```

Comment: And why do you use `{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, *Ptr}` instead of `{0x1, 0x2, 0x3, Ptr}`?

Comment: `frame` is an array whose length is determined at compile time. As yourself how the compiler can do that, and meet your needs.

Comment: @enedil That wouldn't work at all, it wouldn't even compile.

Comment: If "Hello" is passed as a `char *`, what is going to happen trying to pick it up as a `uint8_t *` in the function? Do you pass in a pointer to a long enough space to hold all the data? (a single 64 bit integer should be enough, but what are you doing with an array?) I'm concerned about the { } constant array -- will it be updated with Ptr or *Ptr at run time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your question doesn't make any sense.

You probably want something like this:

```
uint8_t frame[8] = { 1, 2, 3 };

memcpy(frame + 3, "Hello", 5);
```

Note that `frame` must have room for the characters, and that `memcpy()` is being used to avoid writing  the `'\0'`-terminator that strings have.